# Can't run Python from Excel (xlwings)

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

I'm quite new to xlwings and I'm runing code from VBA in order to excecute a python script that writes some text in Excel.

The problem is when I run the VBA code, it seems to excecute python but my excel sheet doesn't change.
However, if I run the python script from python, it works just fine, even if the Excel file is already open.

VBA code is the following:

```
Sub Botón1()
Dim obj As Object
Dim pyexe, pyscript As String

Set obj = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
pyexe = """C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe"""
pyscript = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Prueba.py"

obj.Run pyexe & pyscript, 1, True
End Sub
```

And python code is the following:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('Libro1.xlsm')
sht = wb.sheets['Hoja1']
sht.range('A1').value = 'Hi!'
```

Both files (Libro1.xlsm and Prueba.py) are saved inside the same folder.
When I run excel macro it opens the cmd prompt but nothing happens in Excel spreasheet.
I have not installed xlwings add in, but I believe it is not necessary to do it, in order to do what I'm trying to do.

Can you please help me find what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was reading this article:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-get-the-command-window-to-stay-open-after-running-a-command-line-tool/

And it explains using .run is equivalent to calling Cmd.exe.
If I open cmd I just need to write my python file name with .py extension to run it.
So I figured out "pyexe" is not necessary.

The solution:

```
Sub Botón1_Haga_clic_en()
Dim obj As Object

Set obj = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
obj.Run "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Prueba.py", 1, True

End Sub
```